EF Core: map a simple list of strings into a table
Suppose we have the following class:
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private readonly List<string> _helpers = new();
    public IEnumerable<string> Helpers => _helpers;
}

With NHibernate, I can map the Helpers property into an external table like this:
// using fluent NH class
HasMany(gt => gt.Helpers)
                .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
                .AsBag()
                .Table("OtherTabble") // table that keeps the Helper's list 
                .KeyColumn("ForeignKey") // foreign key point back to Test
                .Element("DB_Column_name") //name of the column that holds each helper
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.All();

I know that EF Core supports "owned" entity collections, but how can I map the string collection exposed from Helpers into another table's column without creating a new class for holding the string?

I think "without creating a new class for holding the string" seems not possible, when looking at the docs. I would suggest, just creating this new class for holding the string makes it much easier and clearer. Then it could be a regular Entity with a regular foreign key relationship without magic.

Hello. Yes, that seems to be the case. Just asked to be sure that was it. NH still has more features than EF even though it has stopped in time for a long long long time now...
